# Add Place holder Inside views exposed filter , If left empty

Tags: views

How to add placeholder inside views exposed filter , only after submitting it , if left empty? but show results on basis of other exposed filters . This question is different in a way that i want to add place holder only after submitting a query and not pacing it in general.

Comment: What do you mean by placeholder?  Isn't the <Any> option enough?

Comment: No , what i mean is , if in one of text field based exposed filter is left empty  . Then i need to put placeholder like "please enter 'any term' for better results" .  Like in case of Global: Combine fields filter (exposed) .